# OpenCV: image looks strange after merge, but become normal after imwrite?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I write this straightforward code to describe my question:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

input = cv2.imread("./Lenna.jpg")
cv2.imshow('input', input)
cv2.waitKey()

b, g, r = cv2.split(input)
bgr_new = b * 1.1, g * 1.1, r * 1.1

merged_uint8 = cv2.merge(np.array(bgr_new).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow('uint8', merged_uint8)
cv2.waitKey()

merged_float32 = cv2.merge(np.array(bgr_new).astype(np.float32))
cv2.imshow('float32', merged_float32)
cv2.waitKey()

merged = cv2.merge(np.array(bgr_new))
cv2.imwrite('Lenna_output.jpg', merged)
lenna_output = cv2.imread("./Lenna_output.jpg")
cv2.imshow('imwrite and imread', lenna_output)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Link to the image]

The last image handled with `cv2.imwrite()` is what I want.
But how can I get the same result as the last one without having to `cv2.imwrite()` it

Comment: you didnt imshow after merged = cv2.merge(np.array(bgr_new)) ... does that state look ok? Is it different from the uint8 version?

Comment: probably an overflow in the as_uint8 version which is handled by merge and imwrite by saturate_casting

Comment: @Micka It is the same as the `float32` version, completely white.

Comment: @Micka How can I take out the magic that happened behind `cv2.imwrite`, so I can get the same result without having to `cv2.imwrite()` it

Comment: imshow handles float to be highest intensity (e.g. white) for value 1 or bigger and smallest intensity for value 0 or smaller. So if your value is for example 25 it is very bright if shown as float but quite dark if shown as uint8. BUT if you have a value bigger than 255, an overflow will occur for uint8. So if value is 256 it will become 0, 257 becomes 1, 258 becomes 2, and so on. opencv's imwrite has a saturate cast included, which clips values to maximum of 255 and minimum of 0. So if you manually make sure that no value is bigger than 255 after b * 1.1, g * 1.1, r * 1.1 it should work

Comment: or, if you want to use the float32 way, you have to divide all values by 255 to get most values in a range between 0 and 1

Comment: @Micka Thanks! Greate answer.

Comment: @Micka You can elaborate your comment as an answer